# How to create a node.js Native Image with GraalVM

Tags: javascript, node.js, graalvm

I am trying to create a native image from a simple  node.js `example.js` application.

When running the application with:

```
 node --native -i --native example.js
```

then the application is starting and working as expected.

Now I would like to create a native image. I tried the following command:

```
 native-image --language:js example.js
```

however it is not working, because of the error:

```
Build on Server(pid: 77626, port: 64052)
[example.js:77626]    classlist:   3,964.04 ms
error: Main entry point class 'example.js' not found.
Error: Processing image build request failed
```

As a resolution I created a main entry point in `example.js` such as:

```
function main(args) {
  console.log("Main app started")
}
```

however this doesn't work.

Is there a way usually native images are create for js/node.js applications?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. Currently, as of Dec 2018, creating GraalVM native images for node.js applications is not possible. The native image utility takes Java bytecode and compiles it ahead of time. GraalVM JavaScript engine is a Java program and can be compiled as a native image. This is what you actually run when you execute `$GRAALVM_HOME/bin/js`. It still loads JavaScript at runtime, interprets it and compiles it just-in-time to machine code.

GraalVM's node implementation is a normal `node`, a native application, with the JavaScript engine replaced by the GraalVM's one.

The GraalVM team is experimenting with possible ways to save precompiled parts of the JavaScript programs, maybe a standard library, or parts of your application, but when this can become available and in which form is unclear.

Comment: Is there any timeline if this will be included anytime soon ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT there are two sides to JS support in GraalVM: "vanilla" JS support and nodejs support.

Oleg's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53749052/202168 explains clearly why building a native image for a nodejs app is not possible.

However it appears that it is possible to build a native image that runs "vanilla" JS:
https://www.graalvm.org/examples/native-image-examples/#polyglot-capabilities

> You can also experiment with a more sophisticated `ExtListDir` example, which takes advantage of GraalVM’s Java and JavaScript polyglot capabilities.

The code for that example is found at:
https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-demos/blob/master/native-list-dir/ExtListDir.java

In this case there is a Java 'wrapper' for the JS app. I believe this is a necessary part - in other words the GraalVM does not "compile JavaScript to native" but rather it compiles a Java app which includes a Javascript engine implemented in Java.

Maybe this is what Oleg means by *"The GraalVM team is experimenting with possible ways to save precompiled parts of the JavaScript programs"* i.e. to have some standard Java boilerplate for running JS apps, so you could directly compile a pure JS app to native image. I guess this would effectively be something like Node or Deno but implemented in Java.

The other side of the problem is if you want to use NodeJS features or include code from npm modules in your JS app.

GraalVM states that the Javascript engine implements ES11, basically all of modern JS:
https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/js/JavaScriptCompatibility/

It seems like it might be possible to use JS tooling like http://browserify.org/ to convert nodejs JS code into "vanilla" JS that could be run by Graal's JS engine.

Then with appropriate Java wrapper code you could compile all that into a native image.